# How can I combine variable and strings together and show varable in PHP?

Tags: php

### I need to combine and show variable but now not show variable;

I need to combine and show variable but now not show variable;
someone can help me fix it
someone can help me fix it

```
$ab1 = 20;
$ab2 = 30;

$x = 1;
while ($x < 3){


echo '$ab'.$x;

$x++;} 

result $ab1 $ab2 / I need to show variable
```

Comment: "I need to show variable" - what does that mean? What's the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${}` to create dynamic variable name, so do:

```php
echo ${'ab'.$x};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should help

```
$ab1 = 20;
$ab2 = 30;    

$x = 1;

while ($x < 3){

$result = ${'ab'.$x};

echo $result . PHP_EOL; 

$x++;
}
```